# Windows 10 application won't save view settings

Tags: windows-10, snipping-tool

I have got a little issue for a colleague. When using application called "Snipping Tool", folder view settings won't last. As an example, when she takes a screenshot, then clicks on "Save As", chooses "Details", saves the file, then once again trying to save another file, default view is set to "Large Icons" again. I have tried to reset Windows folder view, it works fine for every single folder on PC, but not for this application. I have tried myself, settings last when I do it one more time, but for that particular PC, settings won't last.

What I have not tried:

1. New Windows profile. Will this help?
2. Reinstall Windows 10. We are talking about ENT.

For the information:

[image: view settings]

[image: application itself]

Extra options tried:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_Current_User\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\policies\explorer" /v "NoSaveSettings" /t REG_SZ /d "0" /f    
REG ADD "HKEY_Local_Machine\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\policies\explorer" /v "NoSaveSettings" /t REG_SZ /d "0" /f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by resetting Windows 10 profile. There was something happened and this is whythat was the final solution for this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the view *while in the "save as" window*, it's not going to set that folders view. If you open the actual folder (i.e. C:\users\%username%\pictures), change the view, then close the folder, take a screenshot with snipping tool, when you Save As and navigate to that folder it will display in whatever view you just set it as.

Comment: Yes, it is not going to change the view. But, here we are speaking about specific application like snipping tool. Every time she tries to "save as" she is back to "Large Icons" view and settings won't last. This is regarding setting in the app not outside it. When I "Save As" and choose folder view as  "Details" it will last next time I do the same "Save As", but for my colleague it does not last.

Answer (score 0):

Since you note that the dialog view persists on your machine (as it should) and not on your colleague's, the first thing I would check is if your colleague's machine has "maxed out" its saved view capacity (5000). Copy & paste the followign code into a **PowerShell** window to get the count of saved views:

```
((gp "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU").Nodeslots).count
```

Once you hit 5000, views won't save or are quickly lost as the OS has to delete a view before it can save another one.

If views are maxed out, saved views must be deleted by deleting the following two registry keys:

```
HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU
HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags
```

or run this **PowerShell**:

```
'BagMRU', 'Bags' | ForEach{
    ri "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\$_"
}
gps explorer | spps
```

Comment: Checked "((gp "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU").Nodeslots).count" it shows 3138. So this is not a problem I supposed. But big thanks for this one. Would you recommend to run The last script anyway?

Comment: When user restarts PC, then settings are lost. Each day she needs to change view again. Next day saved view resets itself.

Comment: No point in deleting the Bags if they're not maxed out. Is this a standalone machine or joined to a domain? Doess any restart wipe out the view settings or is it an overnight thing?

Comment: Hello Keith. This is a domain joined machine. Seems that another day settings are wiped and user needs to do same view changes again. Seems not a big thing, but user is working with documents and pretty rely on such thing to be fixed, so that is why I cannot get it to work. Would you suggest to try with new user profile?